# Testing variable for null in javascript without causing undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

I am trying to display the results of various javascript null checking techniques.
[codepen](http://codepen.io/jbg8bf/pen/CdGDJ)

However when my variable is actually null It breaks and I get no html output. I get an error in the console "y is undefined". I know it is undefined but I am trying to get it to go through the loop to give you each of the tests results. I can't seem to figure out what could be wrong. Any help would be great.

```
//var y = "im y";

var test1 = function () {
if (typeof (y) === 'undefined') {
    return "test 1 y is undefined";
} else {
    return "test 1 y is defined";
}
};

var test2 = function () {
if (!y) {
    return "test 2 y is undefined";
} else {
    return "test 2 y is defined";
}
};

var test3 = function () {
if (y === null) {
    return "test 3 y is undefined";
} else {
    return "test 3 y is defined";
}
};

var test4 = function () {
if (y == null) {
    return "test 4 y is undefined";
} else {
    return "test 4 y is defined";
}
};

var test5 = function () {
if (typeof (y) === undefined) {
    return "test 5 y is undefined";
} else {
    return "test 5 y is defined";
}
};

var a = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5];
var b = [test1(), test2(), test3(), test4(), test5()];
var somehtml = [];

$.each(a, function (index) {
somehtml.push('<pre>' + a[index] + '</pre>');
var x = b[index];
somehtml.push('<p>' + x + '</p>');
});
$("div#stuff").html(somehtml.join(""));
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are different things in JavaScript. Also, your code needs to go in your question, not on some 3rd party website.

Comment: you should try to put the significant code snippet inside the question

Comment: you can try opening up the web console and see the js error.

Comment: That is the problem, say for example I comment out the var y = im y
my console then gives me an error that y is undefined and no html is output. What I want is for my function to just return that it is undefined.

Comment: @meagar Sorry I edited my post. People on here usually ask for a fiddle or something similar.

Comment: Others have already told you what was wrong, but none have said anything about another thing in your code: `typeof` is not a function, it is an operator. That means that you don't have to put parentheses around the argument. And it returns a string, therefore your test `typeof (y) === undefined` will always fail. Write it as `typeof y === 'undefined'` instead (comparing with a string `'undefined'` instead of the global property `undefined`.

Comment: @some you are correct. I understand that specific test is not the right way to check. That is the point though. That is what I am trying to do is show all the different ways...

Comment: 3 answers and a bunch of comments in a matter of minutes. Nothing here answers your question? If not, how about some guidance?

Comment: @hottea What? Does it make sense to test if the literal number 5 is strict equal to a string `5 === 'a string`? No, it will always return false. The operator `typeof` always returns a string. It makes no sense to test this string against the primitive value `undefined` because it will always be false.

Comment: Correct.I plan to use this as a reference to build on to help learn and teach people javascript. Your feedback is great, I am running into a problem with trying to simulate the test I guess you could say, and display results.

Answer (score 0):

simple check like below

```
if (y) {
alert("defined");
return "test 1 y is defined";    

} else {
alert("not defined");
 return "test 1 y is undefined";   
}
```

Comment: The purpose of me making this is to show what the different functions return. I've edited my example. Now I need it to return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, undefined != null. Second, undefined != 'undefined'.

Your code examples run as expected. I suggest you read about [javascript type coercion and truthy/falsy values](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html). Then start using ["use strict";](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) at the top of your javascript files to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry f I am not getting it properly.I understood your issue from the comments only.
.You are getting the error in console because you are running the other tests like

```
if (!y) {
```

and

```
if (y === null) {
```

even when `y` is `undefined`, which will trigger error in your console.

Your logic should be like, if the variable is found `undefined` then dont do the other tests and else do them.

the test

```
if (typeof (y) === 'undefined') {
```

will be true only if the variable is undefined and null values will pass through

#### updated according to below comments

pls see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fN5jQ/2/). This has the idea I conveyed. Also one more suggestion would be you can think of chaining the functions instead of triggering them in a loop.

Comment: For example, when I open the console and run test1(). I get "test1 y is undefined". which is good that is what is expected. The problem is trying to display this in the html.